# set textstyle asp.net javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, text

Hilfe

how can i set the text-style

Comment: Text style of the "Hilfe" link, or what?

Comment: yes so that the browser show "Hilfe" in Arial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline solution:

```
<a href="..." style="font-family: Arial">Hilfe</a>
```

A better solution would be to use a separarate stylesheet or `<style>...</style>` block so that you can reuse styles for multiple elements:

```
<style>
a { font-family: Arial; } /* this is valid for all links */
a.help  { font-family: Arial; } /* this is valid links with class="help" */
<style>

...

<a href="..." class="help">Hilfe</a>
```

For an introduction to CSS/stylesheets, have a look at [this tutorial](http://w3schools.com/css/).

Answer (score 0):

Specify the font style in the style tag as below-

< href ="javascript:NewWindow =window.open('anleitung.aspx', 'NewWindow' , ' top=81, left=499, width=400, height=400'); NewWindow.focus()" **style="font-family:Arial**">Hilfe